# Orgonize legend in ggplot with facet_grid, geom_density and stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have this code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

Dataset = data.frame(Data = rnorm(100), Factor = c(rep("A",10), rep("B",10)))
graf <- ggplot(data = Dataset, aes(x=Data, fill=..x..)) +   
        geom_histogram(aes(x = Data, y=..density..), binwidth=0.6) + 
        facet_grid(Factor ~ .) + 
        geom_density(aes(x = Data, y=..density..), alpha=.2, fill='red', linetype="dotted", size=1.05) +
        stat_function(fun = dnorm, arg = list(mean = mean(Dataset$Data), sd = sd(Dataset$Data)), colour = "blue", size=1.07, guide = "Normal") +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey25", high = "white")
```

Now, I want to organize the legend: remove the "x" legend and add the legends of stat_function and geom_density. How could I do it? I tried with scale_color_manual but it's not working.

Thanks!

EDIT:

This way it worked out:

```
Data = c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50))
Dataset = data.frame(Data = Data, Factor = c(rep("A",50), rep("B",50)), DensNormal = dnorm(Data, mean(Data), sd(Data)))
graf <- ggplot(data = Dataset, aes(Data, fill=..x..)) +     
        geom_histogram(aes(x = Data, y=..density..), binwidth=0.6) + 
        facet_grid(Factor ~ .) + 
        geom_density(aes(x = Data, y=..density.., colour="dens"), alpha=.2, fill='red', linetype="dotted", size=1.05) +
        geom_line(aes(y=DensNormal, colour = 'blue'),line = 1, size=1.07) +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey25", high = "white") +
        scale_colour_manual(values = c('blue','black'),name = 'Density', labels = c('Normal','Nonparametric'))+
        guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

Now I just want the background of the legend not be in 'red' colour on both, because it's just in the nonparametric line. Any Ideas how?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `override.aes` in `guide_legend` to change the legend `fill`.  Try adding `guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c(NA, "red")))` in `scale_colour_manual`.